# How add compile-only dependency with cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I need to add a compile-only dependency to external lib my in CMake file - referred to as `the_lib` later in the question. By saying compile-only dependency I mean propagating compile-time properties, most importantly `-I` rules.

The library in question is created as a library target using `add_library`. Normally I would simply use `target_link_libraries(my_exec the_lib)`, but this adds both compile-time and link-time properties, i.e., this adds both `-I` and `-l/-L` rules to compilation commands, while I only need `-I`. (If anyone is curios why I need such a setup, this is **because reasons**.)

Please note, `target_include_directories` with something like `${the_lib_SOURCE_DIR}` (or anything similar to that effect) would not work for me, because it wouldn't add include directories necessary for the lib. I need something like `${the_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS}` where `the_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS` would be populated to as -I rules required by `the_lib` - but I didn't find any variable which would match that.

It is worth noting that I can't (or shan't) modify the `the_lib`.

Comment: It seems that you confuse **dependencies** and (automatically-propagated) **properties**. A "dependency" means that `the_lib` should be **built** (whatever this means) before the executable. The most direct way for add dependency is `add_dependencies` command, which creates dependency between *targets* (e.g. between the library and the executable). You talk about `target_link_libraries`, but its main intention to **propagate properties**: linking with a library file(s), including directories, adding compile flags, and so on. So, what do you actually want, dependency or a property propagation?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I might not be very proficient with CMake lingo. I would like whatever effect `target_link_library` has on my compilation flags, but without it's effect on my linking flags. So if it is called 'property propagation', this is what I want.

Comment: Well, this 2-lines comment explains your needs better then the whole your question post. BTW, if you not proficient with some language terminology, then ... just provide a **code**: this is something which is understandable by anyone who familiar with the language. Still, some things remains unclear. What is `the_lib`? Is it a library **target** (created with `add_library`) or a library **file** (`/path/to/lib/so`)? And I cannot understand what is wrong in [lubgr answer(deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54986388/3440745)...

Comment: It is a library target. Lubr's answer would be fine if it worked, but it doesn't add transitive include rules. If you can see deleted answer, you should be able to see our comment exchange as well. I tried edited the question to make it clearer what I want.

Comment: Command [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_include_directories.html) with *INTERFACE* keyword **definitely** adds transitive property. Would you use `target_link_libraries(your_exe the_lib_wrapper)`, then `your_exe` will have include directories contained in `the_lib_includes` variable. But then, it depends on what your actually have. Whether `the_lib` has filled `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` (or, better `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`) property? You may print value of `the_lib_includes` variable with the `message()` command.This is what you have in property.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the library in question doesn't use `target_include_directories` for dependencies. It uses `target_include_directories` to add it's own include files, and than it uses `target_link_libraries` to get all other libraries which it needs (which, in turn, do the same thing). This process brings up all -I (capital i) rules to successfully compile my executable (but -l (lowercase L) rules as well, which I do not need). There is no single property for this library which readily lists all include directories it needs.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The only solution I see right now is to create my own function which re-implement what cmake does - extract LINK_LIBRARIES property from a target, for every library extract it's INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES and do it recursively, forming a list of all include directories. Not sure if it is feasible in Cmake script system... But I will have to do this if no solution would present itself.

Comment: Ok, the problem become clear: You have `the_lib` target with include directories obtained from different sources. And you want to propagate all these include directories, but not the library's file, to the library's "consumer". Yes, currently I see the same solution as you noted. And I recall the question on SO about listing all include directories and libraries in a transitive manner. As far as I remember, listing all include directories is easily feasible, but the same about libraries is much more difficult.

Comment: Just for check the most simple way: doesn't a property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` contain all include directories (including transitive one) for the library?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yep, it is fair depiction of the problem, and nope, I printed all properties of the given library, and there is no single property which would list all includes. If I manage to create a function which does this, I will post it as self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add a compile-only dependency to external lib my in CMake
>   file

By an "external" lib, I take you to mean one that is not part of the same project -- *i.e.* one that is not configured within the scope of the same CMake build system as the target you're trying to build.

> [...] Normally
>   dependencies are added with `target_link_libraries(my_exec the_lib)`,
>   but this adds both compile-time and link-time dependency.

Well no, not necessarily.  As it says on the tin, that adds a link dependency, which you can think of as an `-l` option.  To the best of my knowledge, it does not generate any `-I` options *for external libraries*, or otherwise have any impact on the compilation phase with regard to external libraries.  Similarly, as far as I am aware, it propagates transitive dependencies of any sort only when the the added library is another target configured and built by the same build system.  That is, only for internal libraries, not external ones.

> Please note, `target_include_directories` with something like
>   `${the_lib_SOURCE_DIR}` (or anything similar to that effect) would not
>   work for me, because it wouldn't add include directories necessary for
>   the lib. I need something like `${the_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS}` where
>   `the_lib_INCLUDE_DIRS` would be populated to as `-I` rules required by
>   `the_lib` - but I didn't find any variable which would match that.

I think you're asking for the include directories that would be necessary to successfully use `the_lib`'s headers, in a situation where those headers have their own external dependencies.  There's a reason why you don't find a variable appropriate to that: there is no consistent or standard way to obtain that information for external libraries.  The available techniques depend on `the_lib`.  They will include ***some***, but probably not all, of the following:

- Use a CMake macro provided with `the_lib` or with CMake itself to define a CMake variable conveying the wanted information.
- Use `pkg-config` to read the information from a pkg-config entry associated with `the_lib`.
- Use some technique idiosynchratic to `the_lib`, along the line of Python's `python-config`.
- Analyze `the_lib`'s headers to determine the external packages they depend upon, and search explicitly, individually for those packages' headers.
- Require the user to specify manually for any required packages that are not in the default include path.

There is no magic variable or function in CMake to automatically glean such information, because generally speaking, it is not available from `the_lib`'s headers themselves.  Note, too, that most of those would depend on `the_lib`'s include dependencies being installed in specific places anticipated at `the_lib`'s build time.  That's pretty hard to ensure.

Comment: This is wrong. `target_link_libraries` indeed adds -I rules to compilation commands.

Comment: @SergeyA, I have clarified that I am talking primarily about the use of `target_link_libraries` in conjunction with *external* libraries.  This is all about what information is actually available to CMake, and for external dependencies there is precious little that CMake can automatically determine, unless you count the use of mechanisms such as the first couple on my list.